# RubyGems: sqlite3 too old, and no sudo

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have an account on a server that is not a super user. Because of this I've used RVM to install Ruby, and I've also installed a few gems.

However, the sqlite3-ruby gem does not want to install, since the sqlite3 binary is too old. I've downloaded a newer binary from the sqlite3 homepage, but I can't figure out how to point gem in the direction of the newer binary?

Answer (score 1):

Use with-sqlite3-dir options:

```
$ gem install sqlite3
Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

$ gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/home/ooshro/usr
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3...

ls -R usr/
usr/:
include  lib  share

usr/include:
sqlite3ext.h  sqlite3.h

usr/lib:
libsqlite3.a  libsqlite3.la  libsqlite3.so  pkgconfig

usr/lib/pkgconfig:
sqlite3.pc

usr/share:
doc

usr/share/doc:
libsqlite3-dev

usr/share/doc/libsqlite3-dev:
changelog.Debian.gz  changelog.gz  changelog.html.gz  copyright  README

$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-head [ i386 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your PATH environment variable to have the directory where your own sqlite3 binary resides.